# Python: split a text into individual English sentences; retain the punctuation

Tags: python, split

I am trying to make a function, takes a string/text as an argument, return list of sentences in the text. Sentence boundaries like`(.,?,!)` should not be removed.

I don't want it to split on abbreviations (`Dr.` `Kg.` `Mr.` `Mrs.`, e.g. `"Dr. Jones"`).
Should I make a dictionary of all abbreviations?

---

**Given input:**

```
input = "I think Dr. Jones is busy now. Can you visit some other day? I was really surprised!"
```

**Expected output:**

```
output=['I think Dr. Jones is busy now.','Can you visit some other day?','I was really surprised!']
```

---

**What I've tried:**

```py
# performing somthing like this:
output = input.split('.')
# will produce
'''
['I think Dr', ' Jones is busy now', ' Can you visit some other day? I was really surprised!']
'''

# where as doing
output = input.split(' ')
# will produce
'''
['I', 'think', 'Dr.', 'Jones', 'is', 'busy', 'now.', 'Can', 'you', 'visit', 'some', 'other', 'day?', 'I', 'was', 'really', 'surprised!']
'''
```

Basic assumption is that the text intput is not anomalously punctuated!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, what have you tried so far?

Comment: you want sentence tokanization, this is a non-trivial problem that is a part of natural language processing. you should probably just use a natural language processing library that does this, e.g. `nltk` or `spacy`

Comment: Please go through this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This question should have been closed after clearing pending edits.

Comment: wow, it seems like I'm not allowed to ask Q as a beginner here. Yes tried, but I failed to do so, that's why asking the Q. I have used split() and join too but still splitting in the abbreviations.

Answer (score 2):

A clumsy way of achieving it is as follows:

```py
abbr = {'Dr.', 'Mr.', 'Mrs.', 'Ms.'}
sentence_ender = ['.', '?', '!']

s = "I think Dr. Jones is busy now. Can you visit some other day? I was really surprised!"

def containsAny(wrd, charList):
    # The list comprehension generates a list of True and False.
    # "1 in [ ... ]" returns true is the list has atleast 1 true, else false
    # we are essentially testing whether the word contains the sentence ender char
    return 1 in [c in wrd for c in charList]

def separate_sentences(string):
    sentences = []    # will be a list of all complete sentences
    temp = []         # will be a list of all words in current sentence

    for wrd in string.split(' '):  # the input string is split on spaces
        temp.append(wrd)           # append current word to temp

        # The following condition checks that if the word is not an abbreviation
        # yet contains any of the sentence delimiters,
        # make 'space separated' sentence and clear temp
        if wrd not in abbr and containsAny(wrd, sentence_ender):
            sentences.append(' '.join(temp))  # combine words currently in temp
            temp = []                         # clear temp, for next sentence
    return sentences


print(separate_sentences(s))
```

Should produce:

```
['I think Dr. Jones is busy now.', 'Can you visit some other day?', 'I was really surprised!']
```

Comment: Thank you @anurag for explanation, as new to this field, may I ask  >>>return 1 in [c in wrd for c in charList] how is this list comprehension actually like I can understand for c in charList: but not rest of it. Can we do it under one function? May I also ask what temp=[] doing at the end? sorry asked so many Qs.

Comment: @jay.andrea added comments to the code to explain!