# Split lines into sentence with Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a txt.file which contains text such as:

```
John Simon ; 4
 just cool !
words and without words .
one big   star  : ) ) ; 5
offen good book .
deep complex  story .
recommend .
; 5
unbelievable story  ; 5
```

I want to get the following output:

```
John Simon ; 4
just cool ! words and without words .one big star  : ) ) ; 5
deep complex  story .recommend .; 5
unbelievable story  ; 5
```

How can I get this output with Python?

Comment: Try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65507581/14739759